# Emacs: set compilation command per-buffer

Tags: emacs

so, suppose I have a file file.c, and a file anothr.c. I would like to set the compilation command for each of those files separately, say: `gcc -Wall -O3 -o f file.c`, and `gcc -Wall -std=c99 -o a another.c`. How can I set the `gcc` command for that buffer so that every time I open it, it knows how to compile it? Is there something with the `// -*-` directive or something like that? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use the directive in the file, and also set other value.  Try this in line one or two:

```
// -*- compile-command: "gcc -Wall -O3 -o f file.c" -*-
```

and then re-load the file with `C-x v` so that the setting takes effect.

I sometimes set things like `c-indent-level: 4; c-basic-offset: 4;` in there too.

Comment: `C-x v` apparently means `revert-buffer`. Not a default binding for me.

Comment: It might be mode dependent. I think I (decades ago) set programming mode to derive from text mode.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for are called [*file local variables*](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Variables.html), or sometimes just "local variables", per the in-comment declarative format described [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables).

In addition to the syntax given in [Dirk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540793/emacs-set-compilation-command-per-buffer/4540977#4540977), you can write a "local variables" block at the end of your file:

```
/* Local Variables: */
/* compile-command:"gcc -Wall -O3 -o f file.c" */
/* End: */
```

You can use the interactive function `add-file-local-variable` to help maintain this list if you don't want to type each entry manually.