# how to save keyboard operation time in compiling with emacs for erlang?

Tags: emacs, erlang

When using emacs for writing erlang source code, I have made the following configuration.
In the emacs, 6 windows are open at the same time, 4 windows for source code writing, 1 windows for terminal shell, 1 windows for erlang shell.

After one source code modification, I have use command `"m-x ter`" to switch "terminal shell", then using "`m-p`" for recovering last history command, then pressing "`enter`" to run.
Then using "`c-x, left` " to switch to erlang shell, then press `m-p` to repeat last command.

The above two switch process seems a little long, could you have better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `compile` function is the general mechanism for such things, and the `compile-command` variable tells it what to do (as a shell command to run).

By default, the command is `make`, so if you have a Makefile, you're already sorted.

If not, and writing one isn't appropriate, then you can customise `compile-command` for your files, perhaps using local variables.

[File-local variables for this purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540793/emacs-set-compilation-command-per-buffer) are covered in the linked Q&A.

You can also use [Directory-local variables](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DirectoryVariables) if you want it to automatically apply to all files under a given directory.

Or if there's a general pattern which can be applied to all erlang files, everywhere, then you might set up `compile-command` using the erlang mode hook.

Finally, you can just supply the command on demand. Called interactively, <kbd>M-x</kbd> `compile` prompts you for the command to run, and uses the previous command as the default for the next time.