# Finding the buffer file name in Emacs when compiling

Tags: emacs

I am trying to set up Emacs so that when I choose "Compile.." in the menu, Emacs executes "make filename" on the command line. I am trying something like:

```el
(setq compile-command (concat "make " (file-name-sans-extension
                                       buffer-file-name)))
```

but it doesn't work - it looks like Emacs is is looking for a file-name for the `*scratch*` buffer, which doesn't have one. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

UPDATE: as suggested by Cheeso, a hook fixes the problem. Here is a version that works for me:

```el
(defun cur-file ()
  (file-name-sans-extension
   (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name (current-buffer)))))

(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
          (lambda()
            (set (make-local-variable 'compile-command)
                 (concat "make " (cur-file)))))
```

Comment: n.b. You should either accept Cheeso's answer, or post your own solution as an answer and accept that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - a couple options for you.

- **Simple**: define a [file-local variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Local-Variables.html).  In the header comment of your file just include something like

  ```
   // -*- compile-command: "gcc -Wall -O3 -o f file.c" -*-
  ```

  For more details, see:
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4540977/48082
- **More elaborate** - there is a module called `smarter-compile.el` available [on the marmalade repo](http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/smarter-compile/2012.4.9).  It allows you to define some rules for guessing the `compile-command` to use for a particular buffer.  Like, if there's a makefile, use MAKE; otherwise, if the file is a .c file, use gcc; etc.

  This is nice if you don't want to insert comments into every file, or if you have a myriad of different kinds of files and projects that you work on.

ps: the reason your simple `setq` isn't working, I'd guess, is that you are not evaluating it in the buffer that is being edited.  Probably you want to put that into your personal `xxxx-mode-hook-fn`, where xxx is the mode of the file you are editing.

Comment: Hmm, not sure I like the first option, but you're right: Emacs seems not to evaluate the expression locally. I've posted the fix, that works for me, with a hook.

Comment: just FYY this response explains why this solution works: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12758033/54848