# One compile command per buffer, not directory

Tags: emacs, emacs24, emacs23

I am often editing `foo.cpp` and `bar.cpp` (or `foo.tex` and `bar.tex`) in one directory.

During these edit sessions, I run `make foo` and `make bar` many times.

At some point with Emacs 23, I needed to type `make foo` and `make bar` just once on the respective buffer. Any subsequent invocation of the `compile` command would reuse the command last used on that buffer.

Now with Emacs 24.3.50.1, this settings has become even worse than it was (with Emacs 21/22?). There, one compile command was saved per directory. Now it's one command for all buffers.

How do I recover the previous setting? I am **not** interested in [polluting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540793/emacs-set-compilation-command-per-buffer) every `.cpp` and `.tex` file with file-local variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the applicable variables buffer-local.

```lisp
(eval-after-load 'compile
  '(progn (make-variable-buffer-local 'compile-command)
          (make-variable-buffer-local 'compile-history)))
```