# pandoc-mode: how to express pandoc command option with pandoc-mode?

Tags: emacs, pandoc

On the command line, I need to do the following:

```
pandoc --variable=subparagraph try.md -o try.pdf
```

How do I achieve the same with pandoc-mode?

I studied pandoc-mode, it seems that it's related to specifying options. But I tried, couldn't get it working.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### General way

If you want to make a precise control, the generalised way as pointed out by @jpkotta is perhaps a way forward.  That is, type `M-x compile` and the entire command of `pandoc`, including the filename of the buffer (`try.md`).  I do not know how to set a compilation command per-buffer for a markdown file.

#### pandoc-mode way

However, in this specifi example (and in a vast majoriy of cases with pandoc), it would be better (easier) to use the native pandoc-mode way; that is, set up the required options first and run the conversion command every time you want.  Here is the procedure, based on GNU Emacs Ver.25.3.1 and pandoc-mode Ver.20180122.108.

In `pandoc-mode`, you can set the environment via the pandoc-mode option panel, which is invoked by typing `C-c /` or `M-x pandoc-main-hydra/body` from the buffer you are editing (`try.md` in this case).  Then, do as follows.

Note the following procedure is based on the command interface.  Alternatively, if the tool-bar is available in your Emacs environment, the same thing should be possible via GUI by clicking `Pandoc` tab in the tool bar (I don't go in detail).  Also, for clarity, I am assuming you return to the main menu by pressing `b` (maybe multiple times) after each step, though you may not have to in reality, depending how and what you do.

1. **Input format**: Select it by `I` (Input format) and `m` (Markdown).

   - It seems this command exits the option panel; so you need to invoke `C-c /` again after this.
2. **Output format**: Select it by `O` (Output format) and `l` (LaTeX).  There is no PDF option here. See the [author's description](https://joostkremers.github.io/pandoc-mode/#creating-a-pdf) to find why it is LaTeX.  I believe the native pandoc does so, too, internally (you can check it via `pandoc --verbose` option).
3. (Optional) **Output filename**: Set it by `o f o YOUR_OUTPUT.pdf[RET]` (Options → Files → Output file).  In this specific case, you can skip this, because `try.pdf` is the default PDF filename converted from `try.md`.

   - nb., if you want to cancel it, that is, to set it back to the default, type `o f C-u o` (from the main menu).
4. **Command-line option**: To set `--variable=subparagraph`, type `o w v subparagraph[RET] t[RET]` (Options → General writer options → Variables)

   - I *think* "t" works in this case, though it is saved as a string rather than the true value.  It would raise an error in executing the following step, if you specify nothing here.
   - nb., to cancel it (all of the variables),  type `o w C-u C-u v` (from the main menu).
   - The manual (*info*) warns:

     > they only apply to the current file *and* the current output format.
5. **Run**: To generate a PDF, type `p` (or, if it is from the buffer, the sequence is `C-c / p`.  Alternatviely, via tool bar, navigate "Pandoc" > "Creat PDF")

   - nb., again, PDF creation is exceptional; for any other runs of `pandoc`, it is `c` (Run Pandoc)

Finally, the command-search path must be correctly set so that pandoc-mode can find the commands `pandoc` and `pdflatex` (or similar).  My `.emacs` contains the following lines:

```
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/local/bin")))
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/Library/TeX/texbin"))
```

That's it.  Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about pandoc, and even less about pandoc-mode.  So here's a generic answer:

Use `M-x compile` to run a command (asynchronously) and get the output in a `*compilation*` buffer.  If certain regexps are set up correctly, you get hyperlinks to warnings and errors in the compilation buffer.

You can set `compile-command` as a file local variable ([Emacs: set compilation command per-buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4540793/245173)).

I use the package [`multi-compile`](https://github.com/ReanGD/emacs-multi-compile) to have a number of compilation command templates.